# jQueryUI accordion questions

Tags: jquery-ui

Few questions regarding [jQueryUI's accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion), this is the simple code I've got:

```
 <h3><a href="#">Section 10</a></h3>
<div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
</div>
```

1. Is it possible for the divs inside the accordian to have dynamic content?
2. I know it's possible with the theme roller to change the little arrow icon, but how do I put a small image icon in the H tag as well? no matter what I try doesn't show up, only the H tags text.
3. Is it possible to have some of the accordions bars locked, so they can't expand? while others still can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for the divs inside the accordian to have dynamic
>   content?

Yes. You should be able to replace the contents of the entire `div` without anything terrible happening. You can accomplish this by giving the `div` that you want to replace the contents of an `id` and then when you want to replace the contents just use `.html`:

```
$("#id").html("<content>")
```

---

> I know it's possible with the theme roller to change the little arrow
>   icon, but how do I put a small image icon in the H tag as well? no
>   matter what I try doesn't show up, only the H tags text.

I didn't have trouble adding an image to the header, although it did seem to work better if you added the `img` inside of the `a` tag that lives inside the `h3` tag:

```
<h3><a href="#">Section 1<img src="http://www.placekitten.com/20/20" /></a></h3>
```

You can use CSS to space the image accordingly.

---

> Is it possible to have some of the accordions bars locked, so they can't expand? while others still can?

Sure thing. This one really should be possible via the API, but you can hook up an event handler that prevents the accordion's event handlers from firing when you click the `h3` tag:

```
// Disable the second tab in accordion #accordion
// Note that this could really be any selector you want, as long as it selects 
// accordion header elements.
$("#accordion h3:eq(1)").click(function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

**Here's an example of all of these things working:** http://jsfiddle.net/TX8z6/ *(fixed an IE bug)*

Comment: Few things. First regarding the image in the h tag, when I do this..
<img src="_images/smallIcon.png" width="24" height="24" /> or 
<img src="_images/smallIcon.png"/> it doesn't work, no image appears, but yours does, I'm running mine from my local server, so maybe it's some kind of path issue or accessibility issue?

Regarding disabling the 2nd h3 tab, when I click on it it still opens up?

And the dynamic content, it's appearing outside the content area for the last bar, not inside.

Comment: @Phil: I'm not able to open the second tab ("Section2"; when I click it nothing opens). Click the button labeled "Dynamic content" to insert new content into the first tab (should have been more clear about that). As for the image, I would make sure that your path is correct.

Comment: Section 2 opens up for me no problem, I was testing it in IE8, but then I tested it in the latest version of FF, and it didn't open up so it's an IE8 issue. Thanks now I see the dynamic content. In regards to the image, I was using <base href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/" /> and that was messing things up. Don't suppose you do freelance work? :)

Comment: Phil, I'll get it working in IE8. And unfortunately I don't have the time lately `:-/`